# Send csv data with Guzzle as a chunked request

Tags: php, rest, http, guzzle

I want to upload CSV data to a REST API (that only excepts CSV data at a certain enpoint).

The source of the CSV data is an upload by a user. The uploaded format can either by CVS,ODS or XLSX spreadsheet data.

When the user uploads a CSV file - I just do (simplified):

```
$handle = \fopen($tempFile, 'r');
$client->post('/import', ['body' => $handle]);
```

This works and is easy to todo. But when a user uploads XLSX for instance, then I currently loop through the rows from the first sheet and create a resource with fputcsv.

```
use Box\Spout\Reader\ReaderFactory;

$reader = ReaderFactory::create('xlsx');
$reader->open($tempFile);
$handle = \fopen('php://temp', 'r+');
/** @var $reader \Box\Spout\Reader\XLSX\Reader */
foreach ($reader->getSheetIterator() as $sheet) {
    /** @var $sheet \Box\Spout\Reader\XLSX\Sheet */
    foreach ($sheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
        \fputcsv($handle, $row);
    }
    break;
}
$reader->close();
$client->post('/import', ['body' => $handle]);
```

I am looking for a way to optimize the procedure (XLSX import) with regards to memory consumption and performance.

Is it possible with guzzle to send a request from within the `foreach ($sheet->getRowIterator() as $row)` as a chunked request without creating the complete resource with fputcsv first? I hope this makes sense. Maybe this would not even be a optimization...

Comment: This would be with Guzzle 6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accordingly to the GuzzleHttp documentation, the library uses php streams:

http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/psr7.html#body

So you can create a stream for your request and then write the contents to it line by line using the `write` method from the PSR7\StreamIntefrace class as defined in:

https://github.com/php-fig/http-message/blob/master/src/StreamInterface.php#L115

BTW, as you can read in the Guzzle docs, the stream itself uses the `php://temp` as you already do, with only optimization that if the stream is larger than 2MB it will swap to disk preserving exceeding memory.